# How to duplicate table with more than 500 rows in PhpStorm

Tags: sql, phpstorm

I try to duplicate a table using DB tools of PhpStorm from SQL SERVER, this table has 1300 rows, when I run the code to duplicate table, the new table got just 500 rows.

This is the code that I use to duplicate:

```sql
SELECT * INTO TableBK FROM OldTable
```

If I use this code directly in SQL Server Management Studio, duplicate is successful but PhpStorm.

What could I do to get all records in new table using PhpStorm?

Also I try

```sql
SELECT TOP 2000 * INTO TableBK FROM OldTable
```

But got the same problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's the answer, post answer to qualify you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like PhpStorm defines TOP limit (e.g. by using `SET ROWCOUNT`) which is then used for other queries.

Try changing the value at `Settings | Database | Result set page size` from default 500 to whatever you think will suit you best (setting it to 0 should remove this limit).

Alternatively try adding `SET ROWCOUNT 0;` before the SQL command that you are going to execute in SQL Console.

---

**UPDATE 2022-11-17**

Current 2022.2 IDE version has it changed. It is now located at `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Database | Data Editor and Viewer` screen and would be either `Limit page size to` or `Result set prefetch size` option.

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2022.2/settings-tools-database-data-views.html

Comment: Thank you I just edited Database Settings and worked.